# Get iAd banner's height programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I want to know that how can I get an iAd banner's advertisement's height for current device programmatically in Swift? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by using:

```
CGRectGetHeight(iAdBannerView.frame)
```